# How do I stop blood from clotting except upon exposure to the atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, biology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics, blood

Blood [clots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coagulation) in order to stop bleeding.

The problem is that sometimes it clots when it's not supposed to. This is called [thrombosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrombosis). [It kills a lots of people each year](https://www.heart.org/idc/groups/ahamah-public/@wcm/@sop/@smd/documents/downloadable/ucm_470704.pdf).

I want this to stop happening. Specifically, I want blood to clot only upon exposure to the Earth's atmosphere. Certainly, this will not prevent all diseases and deaths due to clots, since even the best-intentioned of clots sometimes break up and form [emboli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embolus) - free-drifting chunks of material that can block blood vessels - but it will significantly reduce the occurrence of clots under conditions in which they're not supposed to happen.

Assume that the entity we're applying this to is a mammal - one that lives on Earth. **As such, answers must use Earthly biochemistry.**

The question: **how do I make blood clot only upon exposure to the Earth's atmosphere?**

**Good answers will cite some biochemical modification, such as a change in the chemical composition of [platelet-activating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platelet-activating_factor), or a change in the conditions under which [thrombin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrombin) is deployed to [polymerize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerization) [fibrinogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibrinogen) into [fibrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibrin). Additionally, good answers must cite an actual biochemical change, as opposed to saying "well, this *might* happen if we tweak XYZ gene" - hence the "science-based" tag.**

Yes, I recognize that this organism will be significantly more vulnerable to [internal bleeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_bleeding), since its blood will no longer clot upon exposure to anything that isn't similar to the Earth's atmosphere. No, I don't care.

EDIT: if you're voting to close, please explain what's wrong with the question.

Comment: A problem I see is that any gas in the air might end up in the blood from respiration. Perhaps instead, the blood reacts with the organism's sweat or some other skin secretion, it might talk longer to clot as the blood and sweat would have to mix a bit, but it might still prevent internal clots.

Comment: If anyone would know something new, even for a narrow class of cases, they'd be at the patent office instead of answering on WB questions.

Comment: Also, the "Blood clots in order to stop bleeding." [is false](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/blood-clotting) - there are multiple causes. In the linked "abnormal blood stasis, endothelial injury, abnormal hemostasis, and inflammation"⋯ "an abnormally sensitive clotting system and an increased tendency to form venous thrombi in response to raised circulating estrogen levels"⋯"clot formation of RBCs and albumin was induced when the plasma current value exceeded a threshold of clot formation, even if the sample solutions did not contain a clotting factor (fibrin)"

Comment: Biology is pretty good at making great systems for survival. If there was a better way, biology would near certainly have this. Of course there can be some barriers that biology can't overcome but if it would that it's biologically viable. Only problem is that this chance is very low.

Comment: Opinion based - in both aspects: question based on invalid assumption (clots happen when thrombin - an enzyme - transforms fibrinogen in crosslinked fibrin. Multiple mechanism favor thrombin's action) and asking for simple/istic solution to stop it (if actually interested in different mechanisms, WB would not be the site to raise the question). Also, the Q is tagged "science-based", but expects citations (to be considered "good"). Finally, in spite of many pathways to clots formation (and thus no silver bullet), the questioner doesn't care. VTC

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi A better way to deal with invalid assumptions is to post an answer challenging the premise. I also doubt your contention that wrong premises make questions opinion-based. As for simple/istic solution, the OP does not specifically ask for one, this is your assumption based on your belief that a 'serious' question should be asked elsewhere. The WB.SE does not have this kind of limitation, though. Any question can be asked as long as it is not about what characters should do. Please also note that 'cite' in this question does not refer to academic citations.

Comment: I've worked in a hospital blood bank. Bleeding, including internal bleeding, kills a shit ton of people. Mess it up, and that kills a lot more. it is an incredibly subtle process, and millions of years of evolution has made it better than we can engineer.

Comment: @Otkin "As for simple/istic solution, the OP does not specifically ask for one". Heh, _specifically_, eh? Were I to make my answer vaguely general, how would this serve the quality of the content on WB? Do you think that a `science-based` answer can fit to "make blood clot only upon exposure to the Earth's atmosphere?" into a WB to without transforming it into a scientific journal? [Google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=research+into+blood+clotting) returns over 500k hits. "This is your assumption based [etc]" - an opinion, yes. Expressed as _one_ VTC.

Comment: My two cents on this.. Agree with otkin's *"A better way to deal with invalid assumptions is to post an answer challenging the premise."* . Science is never a matter of opinion. Bad science should not be debated indeed, but it can't be closed: it should be *falsified*. The above faulty premises were effectively debunked by current answers.. I think it is good to have such answers.. a closure would have prevented Mike Serfas and L.Dutch to add  relevant content to WB.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Your argument better fits the criteria of 'too broad'. Please note that questions can be too broad and still not opinion-based. I am also afraid that if we apply your reasoning consistently, every question with a 'science-based' tag will have to be closed.

Comment: @Otkin "every question with a 'science-based' tag will have to be closed" nope. There are many questions in `science-based` that can be answered to the point.

Comment: @Goodies "Bad science should not be debated indeed, but it can't be closed: **it should be falsified**" When it comes to science, there are usually a relatively small number of consistent-to-reality questions and answers when compared with the almost infinite ways to be wrong. So much so that the bullshit asymmetry [is actual and must be accounted for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandolini%27s_law). Please read my first 2 comments, I gave the questioner a chance to correct the question, showing why and how s/he's wrong. No correction occurred for a good while, then I raised my VTC... (ctnd)

Comment: ... There aren't any corrections now. "The above faulty premises were effectively debunked by current answers." I'm in doubt when it comes to good answers to bad questions. I think is preferable to provide hints or references on why the question is bad **as comments** and have the question corrected so it can become a good one or be deleted by the questioner (why may have made a honest mistake that can be corrected). (ctnd)

Comment: (ctnd) I don't want WB sliding into some sort of a Gish gallop, in which the majority of questions are bad and need to be debunked. I cringe to every question on "how do I scientifically justify my (fire/ice/lightning)-dragon ". Up to you and everyone else to assess what ratio of BS questions is acceptable before WB no longer acts as a source of good quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## All bleeding is "internal" if you look at it closely enough

Imagine you get a Covid vaccination.  The dermis, hypodermis, fascia and muscle fascicles are all wounded.  The needle leaves only a tiny hole, and that hole is probably filled with leaked vaccine.

If the blood only clots "on contact with air", you have an external clot plugging up a hole filled with blood.  Any contact can dislodge it and lead to more bleeding, and another purely external clot.

You might be very careful until you heal ... but when will that be?  No clot means no granuloma, no scab formation.  The tissues to the sides of the hole have to regenerate until they fuse together somehow.

At the technical level, there is also the issue that oxygen is not present at a much higher level "outside" the body than "inside".  In a healthy person, nearly as much oxygen gas is dissolved in the blood as can dissolve in an aqueous solution.  (That is in addition to hemoglobin, of course)   Maybe 105 mmHg with *normal* breathing versus 160 mmHg in *dry* air - as [explained here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6420699/), the partial pressure in the atmosphere can be *much* lower than 105 mmHg at high altitude. In outside air, the partial pressure of oxygen can go down with humidity (the water in the air dilutes the other gases, if pressure is equal) as it does in the lungs.

However you slice it, blood is exposed to the atmosphere inside the body and out.  The system we have - using small, exposed fragments of living cells working as a team to explore and think about the damage, using chemical cascades to respond specifically to exposed connective tissue - well, it's just a much better design than what you're proposing.  Unfortunately, it is still far from perfect.

Comment: Agree.. I can add, supposed there is no exoskeleton: there will always exist  some damage, in the process of repair, somewhere inside.. 100% of the time, we don't even notice the repairs. This "new blood" would take away a major tool.

Answer (score 3):

> how do I make blood clot only upon exposure to the Earth's atmosphere?

The modification you need to apply is that the only trigger for clotting shall be exposure to gaseous oxygen, not tissue damage. For example when a part of the protein becomes bound to oxygen, it alters its folding in such a way that starts the formation of clots. More or less what happens when you drip an acid like lemon juice or vinegar on egg white. The actual chemistry of the modification is beyond me.

Gaseous oxygen is not present in the blood stream in significant quantities, it's always bound to hemoglobin, so its presence is sign that the blood is in contact with the outside.

Oh, this also means that if the creature starts bleeding underwater will be doomed, as the oxygen concentration is way lower.

Comment: Underwater won't be the only problem. Even a simple bruise won't heal.

You need to invent a seperate mechanism that allows the body to fix internal damage, because even external wounds come with internal damage.

Comment: I think this wouldn't work. The gas exchange in the lungs could still trigger this reaction, making it lethal in minutes.